# Java MySQL DISTINCT for Multiple Columns

Tags: java, mysql

I have two columns in my DB with team names in each column. But, sometimes a team could be in one column, and sometimes it can be in the other column. I want to create a list of distinct, unique, names from both columns combined.

Maybe for further explanation, what I'm trying to say is combine the two columns and then run a distinct query on the combined data to get only unique names out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union` to get a distinct list

```
select team1 as team from your_table
union 
select team2 from your_table
```

Comment: So will the result set have only unique team names? Or does this just return a list of the two combined teams and then I have to run a DISTINCT query?

Comment: `union all` would return the total list, but just `union` reduces it to the distinct values